# Adding Laravel dependency in non-class helper files

Tags: php, laravel, helper, laravel-6, laravel-upgrade

I recently upgraded Laravel version in the project to 6.x.

Now I know the `helpers` class have been removed from Laravel 6.0 version.

But anyway I need to keep the [root-dir]/helpers.php file which is functions oriented, non-class file containing general purpose helper functions.

In that file I need to replace all the custom functions starting with `str_` like `str_contains` with `Illumimnate\Support\Str` counterparts like `Str::contains`. For example:

```
if(!function_exists('is_bot'))
{
    /**
     * userAgent is the user-agent header
     * from the request object
     * @param $userAgent
     * @return bool
     */
    function is_bot($userAgent)
    {
        return str_contains($userAgent, config('bot_check'));
    }
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `namespace` and `use` within class files. You could transform your `helpers.php` file into a class like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Helper
{
    public static function is_bot($userAgent)
    {
        return Str::contains($userAgent, config('bot_check'));
    }
}
```

And call `is_bot` function inside your Laravel application with `\App\Helper::is_bot($userAgent)`.

Answer (score 0):

The helpers removed due to a guy being complaining about them however they moved it to a new package
https://github.com/laravel/helpers

Link to laravel's pull request
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26898